# Как избавиться от e в числе в Python

Tags: python, pandas

Ребята, привет! Помогите, пж, работаю в JupyterNotebook, мне необходимо

1. Взять длинное число, которое у меня изначально имеет тип данных float и вид по типу 1.111222e+08, и перевести его просто в длинное число, без е
2. Перевести это в строку именно. Как мне стоит это сделать? Если переводить сразу в строку, сохраняется также строка с этим e+08.

Answer (score 2):

[Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

`f'{1.111222e+08:f}'` → `'111122200.000000'`